# Two models inside one watch function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, watch

Suppose if I have a watch function that watches a model like this..

> ```
>  $scope.$watch('number', function () {
>    $scope.number = $scope.number.replace(/\D/, '');
>    $scope.number = $scope.number.replace(/\s+/g, '');
>    $scope.number =  $scope.number .replace(/[\W]/g, '');
>    });
> ```

This function restricts user from entering special characters and alphabets in the input text box.

And I have another text box which uses another model say `ng-model="faxNumber"`

Can I add this model name as well in my watch function or should I use a different watch function?

Thanks

Comment: I think a better approach will be is to set the type as `number` and then use validators to validate the value than updating the vlaue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use $watchCollection for array of element:

```
$scope.sortableItems = [
    {order: 1, text: 'foo'},
    {order: 2, text: 'bar'},

];

$scope.$watchCollection('sortableItems', function(newCol, oldCol, scope) {
    for (var index in newCol) {
        //apply operation
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Mukund Kumar,but if I have another set of elements can I add that element name inside this watch function?

Comment: no. $watchCollection can be used of only one set of element.we have to write other $watchCollection for other element.